# Base address of a process without DLL injection?

Tags: c++, winapi

With DLL injection, grabbing the base address of the process was as easy as using

```
GetModuleHandleW(0);
```

So I'm trying to grab the address without injection and I can't seem to get it to work. I've Googled some solutions and found others from stackoverflow but they don't seem to work. Here's what I'm using right now. I have the right headers and it compiles. It just doesn't work.

```
DWORD_PTR dwGetModuleBaseAddress(DWORD dwProcID, TCHAR *szModuleName)
{
    DWORD_PTR dwModuleBaseAddress = 0;
    HANDLE hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE | TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32, dwProcID);
    if (hSnapshot != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        MODULEENTRY32 ModuleEntry32;
        ModuleEntry32.dwSize = sizeof(MODULEENTRY32);
        if (Module32First(hSnapshot, &ModuleEntry32))
        {
            do
            {
                if (_tcsicmp(ModuleEntry32.szModule, szModuleName) == 0)
                {
                    dwModuleBaseAddress = (DWORD_PTR)ModuleEntry32.modBaseAddr;
                    break;
                }
            } while (Module32Next(hSnapshot, &ModuleEntry32));
        }
        CloseHandle(hSnapshot);
    }
    return dwModuleBaseAddress;
}
```

I try to cout this address and it just gives me 0. I think it might be the fact that I don't understand the second parameter. I'm just copying what I saw. Here's my main function.

```
int main() { 
   HWND hwnd = FindWindowA(NULL, gameName); 
   int x; 
   if (hwnd == NULL) { 
      cout << "Cannot find " << (string)gameName << " window" << endl; 
      cin >> x; 
      exit(-1); 
   } 

   DWORD procID; 
   GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &procID); 
   HANDLE handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, procID); 

   DWORD playerAddr = 0; 
   playerAddr = dwGetModuleBaseAddress(procID, _T("starbound.exe")); 
   cout << hex << playerAddr; 
}
```

Some of this may be redundant because I'm just adding it to what I had before. I'm just not sure why it's not working.

Comment: Is your process 32 or 64 bit? Also, this question has been asked hundreds of times before. Do more research. And don't ignore return values.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, there is nothing wrong with it, I just tested it on x86 and x64.

Your problem is you need to run as administrator so you have correct security permissions to access the other process and you also should build your project as the same architecture, x86 or x64, as the target process.

If neither of those solutions fix it, then your 'gameName' variable or your module name are defined incorrectly.

Answer (score -1):

If you use your dwModuleBaseAddress as a debug tool, it may be easier to spot the call that fails...

```
DWORD_PTR dwGetModuleBaseAddress(DWORD dwProcID, TCHAR *szModuleName)
{
    DWORD_PTR dwModuleBaseAddress = (DWORD_PTR)-1; // unlikely value...
    HANDLE hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE | TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32, dwProcID);
    if (hSnapshot != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        MODULEENTRY32 ModuleEntry32;
        ModuleEntry32.dwSize = sizeof(MODULEENTRY32);

        dwModuleBaseAddress = (DWORD_PTR)-2;

        if (Module32First(hSnapshot, &ModuleEntry32))
        {
            do
            {
                --dwModuleBaseAddress;
                if (_tcsicmp(ModuleEntry32.szModule, szModuleName) == 0)
                {
                    dwModuleBaseAddress = (DWORD_PTR)ModuleEntry32.modBaseAddr;
                    break;
                }
            } while (Module32Next(hSnapshot, &ModuleEntry32));
        }
        CloseHandle(hSnapshot);
    }
    return dwModuleBaseAddress;
}
```

You can also check the error that caused the issue using GetLastError()

```
void PrintLastError()
{
    LPTSTR psz;
    DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
    FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,
        NULL,
        dwError,
        0,
        (LPTSTR)&psz,
        1024,
        NULL);

    _tprintf(_T("Windows reports error: (0x%08X): %s\n"), dwError, (psz) ? psz : _T("(null)"));
    if (psz)
    {
        LocalFree(psz);
    }
}
```

If all else fails, try running this example from msdn https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/ms686849(v=vs.85).aspx

It will print the exact string you want to match, the problem may come from  there.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't solved it, but it did help me. I don't know why I didn't try this before. Basically I just did a cout at certain points just to see how far it got. So it seems that it doesn't even get past the if statement if (hSnapshot != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE). Which implies that HANDLE hSnapshot isn't getting the process. Why doesn't it work? The process is open, and the process ID is correct. I'm doing this: dwGetModuleBaseAddress(procID, _T("starbound.exe")); I have a feeling there's something wrong with this.

Comment: Your process probably doesn't have the necessary security access rights.

Comment: How would I go about fixing that? I tried running Visual Studio as Administrator and it didn't work. I even tried running the .exe file itself as administrator.

Comment: Check that is indeed the problem, check added info in answer

Comment: So I did a PrintLastError() before and after the line where I  think the error is. before the line it says "The operation completed successfully" and after it says "Only part of a ReadProcessmemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed." After this I Googled the error and people were talking about x86 vs x64 and I realize I was running it x86. Now I did it x64 because I have 64 bit Windows.This time it says "The operation was completed successfully" instead of the other error, but it still shows a 0 as the address.

Comment: Have you tried running this example before ?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/ms686849(v=vs.85).aspx  Maybe your filtering doesn't work.  The MS example will print all the info you need to check that.

Comment: Just tried it and everything worked fine, no errors.

Comment: The exact string you are looking for is printed now.  And the value you expect.  If GetLastError() returns 0, then the problem can only be with the string compare.

Comment: Okay, I've got it, thanks. Kind of unlucky of me there. Basically my main problem and why all the code I tried before wasn't working was simply not being x64. At the same time, however, the code I picked this time when I fixed it just happened to be wrong.